# Unable to log in to a spring boot OAuth2 Resource Server application from an angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors, oauth2resourceserver

I built a small spring boot application using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server. The tests work well on Postman but not on Angular. The test was working on Angular when I used spring-boot-starter-security.

Here is my pom.xml file, I only added 3 staters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.devskills</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauth2api</name>
    <description>Oauth2 security security with Angular in frontend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my configuration file, I have implemented hardcoded username and password in **InMemoryUserDetailsManager**.

```
package com.devskills.oauth2api.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;
    
    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }
    
    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager user() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("keen")
                    .password("{noop}password")
                    .authorities("read")
                    .build()
                );
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/token").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

}
```

And here is my controller which contains the method `token(Authentication authentication)` which allows to log in.

```
package com.devskills.oauth2api.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.devskills.oauth2api.service.TokenService;

@RestController
public class AuthController {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
    
    private final TokenService tokenService;
    
    public AuthController(TokenService tokenService) {
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/token")
    public String token(Authentication authentication) {
        LOG.warn(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
        LOG.debug("Token requested for user: '{}'", authentication.getName());
        String token = tokenService.generateToken(authentication);
        LOG.debug("Token granted {}", token);
        return token;
    }

}
```

The connection with Angular has no problem because I added this method in the main file of the application.

```
    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
```

Here is the result of the test on Postman, the token is well returned when the login is successful.
[image]

Here is my Angular code that does not work.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  login() {
    const username = 'keen';
    const password = 'password';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)});
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/token', {headers})
                .pipe(
                  map(
                    userData => {
                      sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
                    }
                  )
                );
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    return !(user === null);
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
  }
}
```

And the `login()` method is called with a button on the view through this component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.login().subscribe(
      response => {
        alert('login successfully');
      }
    );
  }

}
```

When I try to login, I get a **401 Unauthorized** error.
[image]

And why do I get this error? Because Spring Boot reports that the Authentication object received as an argument to the `token()` method is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because "authentication" is null
    at com.devskills.oauth2api.controller.AuthController.token(AuthController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
```

This means that the headers sent here `this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/token', {headers})` from Angular are not received by the `token()` method of Spring Boot backend. Why is that? That's what I'm trying to find out.

All help is welcome, Thank you.

Comment: Are you implementing a resource-server or an authorization-server? Read more about OAuth2: users do not "login" to a resource-server. Clients redirect users to an authorization-server when it (the client) needs an access-token to issue requests on behalf of the user. So, technically, it is the client that is is "logged in" and against the authorization-server. Resource-servers just requires requests to be "authorized" (have an `Authorization` header with a `Bearer` token).

Comment: The problem is on the Angular side. The object ```{headers}``` that I pass as an argument here ```this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/token', {headers})``` does not reach the ```token(Authentication authentication)``` method on the Spring Boot side, that's why the ```Authentication authentication``` object always gets null. How can I solve this problem on angular side? The application works fine on Postman

Comment: Sorry, but I still suspect a probkem on the developper side: not understanding OAuth2... A successful request with Postman doesn't mean it was an OAuth2 request to a resource-server

Comment: To be more constructive (as you'll probably never get an answer to your question), maybe should you have a look at [those tutorials I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). The Introduction README contains a **memo of essential OAuth2 notions you should read carefully before rushing to implementation samples**.

Comment: Thanks for your tutorial ch4mp. All http requests sent from Angular work fine. You were right, I had built the backend wrong. Unfortunately I can't post the solution because I rebuilt the project completely.